# React - Key down event first triggers on body then on element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I'm injecting some code which creates a text input into existing pages on the internet.

On some sites, when the user presses some specific keys while focused onto my text input, the event gets captured instead of being bubbled.

I've been trying multiple solutions to prevent this but they do not seem to work:

```
  keyUp = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  };

<Form.Control
            as="textarea"
            onChange={this.updateInput}
            onKeyUp={this.keyUp}
            onKeyPress={this.keyUp}
            onKeyDown={this.keyUp}
          />
```

Is there a way I can prevent this event from being triggered on the body instead of being triggered in my element first?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React how to ignore onClick for child element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60811792/react-how-to-ignore-onclick-for-child-element)

Comment: The `capture` event phase starts from the top per specification so it always flows from `window` through document, body, and so on.

Comment: Can I prevent the capture event from being triggered?

Answer (score 1):

React attaches its event listener to `body` by default, and uses that to trigger its own `SyntheticEvent`

You could try attaching your event in capture mode by appending `Capture` to your event name, as outlined [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#supported-events)

Edit (added for clarification to comment):
Attach an event to your window:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function (evt) {
  if (evt.target.id === 'elementID') {
    //do what you want to, here.
    //if you want to prevent the event propagating:
    evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
    evt.stopPropagation();
  }
}, true);
```

in your jsx:

```
...
<input id='elementID' />
...
```

Comment: Problem is, this still triggers the preexisting event on the page, so I'm guessing it is higher up the tree than my element. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Can you check if your event attached in capture mode, gets triggered? If it doesn't you might need to manually attach an event on `window` in capture mode, and wire it up to your element by assigning it an `id` and check if the `event.target.id` matches in your event handler.

Comment: What do you mean by wire it up? I did end up with capturing the event at `window` level but I want to prevent it from triggering other handlers and only trigger the element's

Answer (score 0):

I've added a listener at `window` level to capture the event and prevent propagation down. Of course if a listener is already added at `window` level this will not work:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", this.keyDown, true);
```